# Split datetime variable in PHP into date and time

Tags: php, date, datetime

How can I reformat/split the datetime data (from a database) into two variables, date and time, and then add them back to the array?

At present `$datetime` contains data such as: `2014-12-03 00:00:00`

I want to split it out into `$date` and `$time`

I have the following, but when I echo out the $date and $time vars they are empty:

```
$datetime = date($data['date_time']);
$date = date_format($datetime,"Y-m-d'");
$time = date_format($datetime,"H:i");
```

Comment: RTFM: http://php.net/date and http://php.net/date_format. They expect a TIMESTAMP as their input, and output strings. You need to convert your date string into a timestamp first: http://php.net/strtotime

Comment: If you turn on warnings, you'll see: "PHP Warning:  date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTimeInterface, string given..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DateTime` objects are created using [`date_create()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php), not `date()`

```
$datetime = date_create($data['date_time']);
$date = date_format($datetime,"Y-m-d");
$time = date_format($datetime,"H:i");
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply do it using [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php#class.datetime), in OOP way

```
$date = new DateTime('2000-12-31 00:00:00');
$dateonly=$date->format('Y-m-d');
$timeonly=$date->format('H:i');
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/k4wCON)

Comment: They are doing that, they're just doing it on a functional way (not OOP).

Comment: @John Conde,Sir, you are doing the same on procedural way

Answer (score 0):

With your current code you can try this :

```
$datetime = date($data['date_time']);
$dateArray = explode($datetime, " ");
$date = $dateArray[0];
$time = $dateArray[1];
```

Comment: This does not work. The result of dateArray is emtpy: `array(1) { [0]=> string(1) " " }`

Comment: This code works if your affirmation is true :

At present $datetime contains data such as: 2014-12-03 00:00:00

This means that your variable $datetime doesn't contain something like 2014-12-03 00:00:00

Comment: it does, as a date. Not as a string.

Comment: The date() function returns a string or false then $datetime should contain a string.

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
$datetime = new DateTime($data['date_time']);
$date = $datetime->format('Y-m-d');
$time = $datetime->format('H:i:s');
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use *strtotime*:

```
$datetime = date($data['date_time']);
$date = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($datetime));
$time = date("H:i:s",strtotime($datetime));
```